$g(A)=0 \Leftrightarrow g(\lambda)E=(\lambda E-A)G(\lambda)$ for some matrix $G(\lambda)$ whose elements are polynomials in $\lambda$. Furuya's book
I am reading "Matrices and Determinants" (in Japanese) by Shigeru Furuya.

Proposition:
Let $g(\lambda)$ be a polynomial in $\lambda$.
Let $A$ be an $n\times n$ matrix.
Then $g(A)=0 \Leftrightarrow g(\lambda)E=(\lambda E-A)G(\lambda)$ for some matrix $G(\lambda)$ whose elements are polynomials in $\lambda$.


Proof:
We can write $g(\lambda)-g(\mu)=(\lambda-\mu)g(\lambda,\mu)$ for some polynomial $g(\lambda,\mu)$.
Since $g(\lambda E)=g(\lambda)E$, $g(\lambda E)-g(A)=g(\lambda) E-g(A)=(\lambda E-A)g(\lambda E,A)$.
So, if $g(A)=0$, then $g(\lambda) E=(\lambda E-A)g(\lambda E,A)=(\lambda E-A)G(\lambda)$.
Conversely, by the equation $g(A)=g(\lambda)E-(\lambda E-A)g(\lambda E,A)=(\lambda E-A)(G(\lambda)-g(\lambda E, A))$, $g(A)=0$.
[Let the $(i,k)$ element of $G(\lambda)-g(\lambda E,A)$ be $h_{ik}(\lambda)$.
The $(i,k)$ element of $(\lambda E-A)(G(\lambda)-g(\lambda E,A))$ is $$\sum_{j}(\lambda\delta_{ij}-a_{ij})h_{jk}(\lambda)=\lambda h_{ik}(\lambda)-\sum_{j}a_{ij}h_{jk}(\lambda).$$ Since this is equal to the matrix $g(A)$ which does not contain $\lambda$, $h_{ik}(\lambda)$ must be $0$ for any $i,k$.]

I cannot understand the above proof.
I think the author didn't prove that $\lambda h_{ik}(\lambda)-\sum_{j}a_{ij}h_{jk}(\lambda)$ does contain $\lambda$ if $h_{ik}(\lambda)\neq 0$ for some $i,k$.
Please explain about this point.

Among all elements of $G(\lambda)-g(\lambda E,A)$, pick the one with the highest degree. Let it be $h_{ik}(\lambda)$ and let its degree be $m$. If $h_{ik}$ is not the zero polynomial, then $\lambda h_{ik}(\lambda)$ has degree $m+1$, while $\sum_{j}a_{ij}h_{jk}(\lambda)$ has degree $\le m$. Therefore $\lambda h_{ik}(\lambda)-\sum_{j}a_{ij}h_{jk}(\lambda)$ has degree $m+1$, i.e., it cannot be a constant polynomial. This is a contradiction because $G(\lambda)-g(\lambda E,A)$ is equal to $g(A)$, a matrix whose elements do not depend on $\lambda$ (i.e., they are constant polynomials). Hence $h_{ik}$ must be zero. As $h_{ik}$ is the polynomial of the highest degree among all $h_{pq}$s, all those $n^2$ polynomials are zero.

user1551, thank you very much for your elegant answer! Thank you very much again!
